# How to populate an HTML canvas with numeric data? Is there a better alternative to create a text grid that can be used for Conway's Game of Life?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an HTML5 canvas and using the stroke() method, ended up with a grid. Below is the code that i have used:

I now do see a grid display. However, i am trying to figure out how to add numeric data to each of the grid columns? Or Alternatively, is there a better way to accomplish this (i.e. to create a 2 dimensional grid and then be able to write numeric values to any specific square) besides using the canvas tag of HTML5?

```
<script>
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,400);

        var hCount, vCount;


        for (hCount=20; hCount<400; hCount+=20) {
            ctx.moveTo(0,hCount);
            ctx.lineTo(600,hCount);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        for (vCount=20; vCount<600; vCount+=20) {
            ctx.moveTo(vCount,0);
            ctx.lineTo(vCount,400);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: maybe a `<table>` element can help?

Comment: If you want 0/1 in each of your cells, then you either have to draw real text - or you make two small images that correspond to your cell size, one containing `0` and one `1`, and then just paint those images at the appropriate position for every cell.

Comment: A simpler way to draw the lines is to draw hCount horizontal lines and vCount vertcal lines ... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#text he basically uses your code as an example on how to use a canvas element.

To quote:

```
context.fillText("x", 248, 43);
```

So if you have your bored in an Array of Arrays called "life"

```
for (i = 0; i < life.length; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < life[i].length; j += 1) {
        ctx.fillText(life[i][j], 30 + 20 * i, 30 + 20 * j);
    }
}
```

Or if all you want to do is use html5 to display a table of numbers... you could use a html table, and skip canvas all together.

Comment: I am planning to code the Game of Life and the canvas is my first step. By numeric data, i imply that 0 would mean a dead cell and 1 would mean an alive cell. I will edit the question as well